Как изменить цвет брейкпоинтов в дебагере NetBeans?
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как изменить цвет брейкпоинтов в дебагере в NetBeans?
А то ничего не видно.

Казалось бы, причем тут PHP?) Просто попробуйте выбрать другую тему

Tools - Options - Fonts & Colors - Annotations
